# Flask login using Azure active directory

Tags: flask, azure-active-directory, flask-login

I'm developing a Web app using azure active directory as login.

I have all validations with azure AD and all is fine, but i want integrate this with Flask_login for manage the user session and block some routes that need a user logged all fail :(.

When I receive the user information from Azure AD, i create a object and try use Login_user, but this show me and error that i don't understand.

this is my code:

[image]
[image]
[image]

error:

[image]

Comment: Post the error, that would help expose the issue.

Comment: oh, yes, i forgot. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

From the error you posted, you aren't working in the application context.
Flask is basically a WSGI microframework. It is about two orders of abstraction above having to manually process each HTML request yourself.
To work within the application context, you need to have your application make the call. See the [following link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/).